# Is it possible to log a method call in java (log4j)?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is it possible to log any method call in log4j Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

No, not without editing either the call-sites or the method itself. I think what you're after is something towards aspect oriented programming. Have a look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for example.

Comment: +1: Logging is the canonical "cross-cutting concern" for aspect-oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with AOP and Java annotations. I would recommend to use [`@Loggable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-loggable.html) annotation and an AspectJ aspect from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/) (I'm a developer):

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

In SLF4J log output you will see method execution time, its parameters, and its name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%I` in your [Log4j conversion pattern](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) to print out the name of the method. **BUT** be warned that "generating caller location information is extremely slow and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue."

Answer (score 0):

How about using (%C.%M.%L) as shown below in log4j.xml

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"
        value="%d - MyApplication - %-4p - (%C.%M.%L) -- %m%n" />
</layout>
```