# log method scope in java with one call

Tags: java, logging

I am learning Java and looking for a solution to log method scope (enter and exit) with in one line of code.  In C++ I had a class that logged the enter scope in the constructor and logged the exit scope in the destructor.  In the method I would create an auto_ptr for the log class.  The result: one line of code to log method enter and exit  scope.  Any Java solutions with the same result?

Thanks

Comment: That seems a little old school and excessive. In the distant past, I used that methodology to debug applications. With the current state of many integrated debuggers, I think you can accomplish the same goals.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374665/is-it-possible-to-log-a-method-call-in-java-log4j

Answer (score 0):

Not without using AOP in some form or another. Using AspectJ or similar it can be a no-liner based on configuration or build parameters. Object scope is handled by the JVM thus unreliable for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The closest uses something like

```
Log l = null; try { l = new Log(); ... } finally { l.exit(); }
```

In Scala you can do it with closures ...