# Java, is it possible - automatic method scope tracing, like macros in C++

Tags: java, c++

I wonder if there's a way to get automatic scope tracing in java.

Ideally I want to get behavior similar to the following C++ code (that automatically picks up function, indentation level, no op in release mode/etc).

```
void bar()
{
    _SCOPE_TRACE(Level_debug);
    _LOG("stuff");
}

void foo()
{
    _SCOPE_TRACE(Level_debug);
    bar();
}

XXX: foo(): entering
XXX:     bar(): entering
XXX:         stuff
XXX:     bar(): leaving, took 400 cycles
XXX: foo(): leaving, took 3000 cycles

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _SCOPE_TRACE(level) scopelog::ScopeLog CONCAT_MACRO(scope,__LINE__)(level, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
#else
#define _SCOPE_TRACE(level) do {} while(0)
#endif

struct ScopeLog {
    ScopeLog(int32_t level, const std::string& scope) : m_level(level), m_indent(false), m_scope(scope.c_str()) { init(); }
    ScopeLog(int32_t level, const char* scope) : m_level(level), m_indent(false), m_scope(scope) { init(); }
    void init()
    {
        if(level < m_level)
        {
            _LOG(m_level, m_scope << ": enter");
            g_indent++;
            m_indent = true;
            m_tickStart = rdtsc_r();
        }
    }
    ~ScopeLog()
    {
        if (g_indent) g_indent--;
        if(level < m_level)
        {
            uint64_t tsc = rdtsc_r();
            _LOG(m_level, m_scope << ": leave, took " << tsc - m_tickStart << " cycles");
        }
    }
    int32_t     m_level;
    bool        m_indent;
    const char* m_scope;
    uint64_t    m_tickStart;
};
```

Comment: These seem similar.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422241/log-method-scope-in-java-with-one-call  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374665/is-it-possible-to-log-a-method-call-in-java-log4j

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/9422241/ - have seen this one, but it's very ugly/lots of code to write. One has to have  try/finally everywhere and manually call tracer. This macro is non-invasive 1 liner.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get most of what you want will be to use the [%M or %l pattern layout parameters](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) using [Apache log4j library](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/).  As the documentation states, generating method name information is really slow, so hopefully this is only being used for debugging.  This won't cover the indentation you want, but there may be a way to use conversion patterns to accomplish it.

The only other way that I could think of to do this would be to use AspectJ to create a pointcut that fires a logging aspect on every method, but to do that, you'd need to use cglib, and I'm not sure it would be much faster than using the existing log4j support.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I looked at log4j. Unfortunate side effect is one has to  manually put in enter/leave log statements before every single return/etc. Or to use try/finally ugliness.

Comment: I like AspectJ idea, will research more. 
disclosure: I'm new to java, have to use it instead of C++.

Comment: OK.  Remember to include cglib in the classpath for your application, so you get pointcut support for classes as well as interfaces.  Your join point is going to look something like `call(*)` - good luck.